# Convert number to Month name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I used the formula:

```
MODE(MONTH(Employees!$B$2:$B$301))
```

to calculate the month that occurs most frequently, and the answer is 11.
I need to convert 11 to November, but the formula:

```
TEXT(MODE(MONTH(Employees!$B$2:$B$301)
```

leads to January. **How can I convert my answer to November?**

Answer (score 1):

(Stolen from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/converting-a-number-to-a-month-name/734b3f7c-eac7-4ca8-937d-935870346fed))
You need to convert it to a date first, then extract the month:

> =TEXT(DATE(2011,*<your value here>*,1),"MMM")

So in your case, this should be the formula:

> =TEXT(DATE(2011,MODE(MONTH(Employees!$B$2:$B$301)),1),"MMM")